# Angular 6 SSR Sass minification with Webpack

Tags: angular, webpack, sass, minify, server-side-rendering

I'm working on an Angular 6 app with SSR. It's an SPA prerendered server side on the first call, so after that the app call the server only through ajax requests.
I put all my style in a bunch of organized scss files. And all theses styles are processed to be css and rendered in the head tag inline.
All is working perfectly except that the css code is not minified, despite I add '?minimized' on sass-loader in webpack configuration.
I search a way to minify this css but I only find solutions where the css is packaged in an external file...
Is there a way to minify this css without to put it in an external file ?

Thank you !

Comment: CSS is not used in server side, so why do you need that ?
Don't you use angular-cli to build browser part ?

Comment: I use Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Prerendering.Prerenderer to render all the SPA on the first load (this include CSS) so all the webpack build is called by this prerenderer and I try to make my scss processed and minified before it is rendered inline in the rendered page that the server serves to the browser.

Comment: Ok Sorry I never tested this .NET renderer. I personally this doc : https://angular.io/guide/universal where you build browser part, build server part (same CSS size as browser) and package server part in one file.

Comment: Yes this .NEt renderer is just something that call angular universal to perform SSR, it's a bit complicated I think but maybe my question is not correctly formulated. Today, my css is rendered inline in the HEAD of the html document, but it's not minified, so I try to know what I need to do in webpack config(I suppose) to make that the processing of SASS file end up as minified string of css.

Answer (score 0):

```
"server": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
  "options": {
    ...
  },
  "configurations": {
    "production": {
      "fileReplacements": [
        {
          "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
          "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
        }
      ],
      "sourceMap": false,
      "optimization": true,
    }
  }
}
```

"optimization": true